# No internet over BES connection - BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, connection, internet-connection

My BlackBerry App is unable to connect to the internet through BES. It successfully connects via Wifi, BIS, GPRS etc but does not detect internet connection over BES. I have checked all the settings and the browser is connecting to the internet but not the App. My connection method is as follows:

```
static String connectionParameters = ""; 
     public static String checkInternetConnection(){
            //String connectionParameters = "";   
            if(CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_NONE)
            {
                connectionParameters=null;
            }    
            else
            {
                if (WLANInfo.getWLANState() == WLANInfo.WLAN_STATE_CONNECTED) {
                    // Connected to a WiFi access point
                    connectionParameters = ";interface=wifi";
                    } else {
                    int coverageStatus = CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus();
                    ServiceRecord record = getWAP2ServiceRecord();
                    if (record != null
                    && (coverageStatus & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT) ==
                    CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT) {
                    // Have network coverage and a WAP 2.0 service book record
                    connectionParameters = ";deviceside=true;ConnectionUID="
                    + record.getUid();
                    } else if ((coverageStatus & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS) ==
                    CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS) {
                    // Have an MDS service book and network coverage
                    connectionParameters = ";deviceside=false";
                    } else if ((coverageStatus & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT) ==
                    CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT) {
                    // Have network coverage but no WAP 2.0 service book record
                    connectionParameters = ";deviceside=true";
                    }

                }
            }

            return connectionParameters;
        }
            private static  ServiceRecord getWAP2ServiceRecord() {
                ServiceBook sb = ServiceBook.getSB();
                ServiceRecord[] records = sb.getRecords();
                for(int i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
                String cid = records[i].getCid().toLowerCase();
                String uid = records[i].getUid().toLowerCase();

                if (cid.indexOf("wptcp") != -1 &&
                uid.indexOf("wifi") == -1 &&
                uid.indexOf("mms") == -1) {
                return records[i];
                }
                }
                return null;
                }
```

Please help!

EDIT: The App is trying to access the server which is available on the intranet. The App fails to access internet (google web service) and intranet (local server) over BES. Can anyone comment?

Comment: For which version of Blackberry OS are you developing? http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11938/Using_the_BES_as_an_intranet__gateway_508965_11.jsp states there are firewall techniques involved, maybe your service is just not allowed? are you trying to connect to a webserver?

Comment: I have developed for OS 6 and onwards. Yes the app tries to connect to a web service. How can I verify whether its firewall settings or the issue is with the connection method?

Comment: @Sarah The BES admin can ban some devices from connectiong to the internet using IT policies. BES connectivity means you can connect to the BES corporate network (think of it as a LAN). Anyway try replacing the flag checks with `CoverageInfo.isCoverageSufficient`.

Comment: @MisterSmith thanks for the reply. Please check the `edit` to the question. The App fails to even access the server on the intranet available on BES. `Whatsapp`, also a third party app, connects over BES successfully but not my written app. Can you comment?

Comment: @Sarah Your code is prone to bugs, uses flags to check coverage and appends suffixes to the URL. That was the old way of making connections and is no longer the recommended approach. Consider using the new [`ConnectionFactory`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/index.html) class. Here's a [simple tutorial](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/34480/Network_API_Overview_1251781_11.jsp).

Comment: @MisterSmith what does BIS and BES connections fall under? Is this the WAP2, TCP_Cellular or something else?

Comment: @Sarah - BES is covered in the approach you are using - in the code you call it MDS.  BISB is something different, your code does not use it.  I recommend this documentation to give you a better understanding of what your code is trying to do: http://developer.blackberry.com/bbos/java/documentation/intro_networking_1984362_11.html.  You will also see in there how you can get access to BISB.  If you do not wish to take the approach recommended by Mister Smith, then clarify which connection method you are trying to use when the app fails to connect.  I'll bet it is NOT BES.

Comment: @PeterStrange reference `clarify which connection method you are trying to use when the app fails to connect`, the app fails to work when Wifi is turned off.The app is installed in a device that is on BES.The server that the app tries to connect to is available in the LAN.It is able to access the server and function normally when Wifi is there.However,with Wifi turned off it fails to work.So the issue is accessing the server in BES?We do not have a BES server available and so cannot debug.Please guide!

Comment: @Sarah - review this link: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Different-ways-to-make-an-HTTP-or-socket-connection/ta-p/445879 to note how different connection strings are used depending on the actual connection method.  You need to confirm that actual connection method that is being used, in other words, what is being set by checkInternetConnection().  You think it is BES but unless you have information from the device, you don't know this. And without this information you are just guessing, I suspect incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

first you check whether you have BES sufficient coverage and this you get when you have BES plan.

Comment: @sarah - sorry missed your comment - see my response.